# JavaScript syntax for multiple condition checking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a JS condition to disable the save button for the following condition;

1. if status is CLOSED OR
2. if my model does not have BOTH UPDATE_GLOBAL and UPDATE_LOCAL privilege

I have written the following code;

```
if ((self.model.get("status") === "CLOSED") || (!self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_GLOBAL") && !self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_LOCAL"))) {
    $("#save").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

Is this the best optimized code? Also are there any unnecessary parentheses (which always confuses me)?

Comment: Take a look at DeMorgan's laws: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws.

Answer (score 1):

You've said

> if my model does not have BOTH UPDATE_GLOBAL and UPDATE_LOCAL privilege

...but that's not what that part of the condition is checking. It's checking if you **don't** have both; if you have just one, the check result is incorrect.

If you want the button disabled for status = CLOSED or your model doesn't have **both** privileges, then:

```
if (self.model.get("status") === "CLOSED" || !(self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_GLOBAL") && self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_LOCAL"))) {
    $("#save").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

> Also are there any unnecessary parentheses (which always confuses me!!)

Yes, you don't need the parens around `self.model.get("status") === "CLOSED"` (but they're harmless).

---

Also note that your code never *enables* the button, it just disables it or leaves it alone. If you also want to *enable* it when the condition for disabling isn't true, then:

```
$("#save").attr("disabled", self.model.get("status") === "CLOSED" || !(self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_GLOBAL") && self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_LOCAL")));
```

or (easier to debug):

```
var flag = self.model.get("status") === "CLOSED" || !(self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_GLOBAL") && self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_LOCAL"));
$("#save").attr("disabled", flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put it like that:

```
if (self.model.get("status") === "CLOSED" || !(self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_GLOBAL") && self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_LOCAL")))
```